# INSERT INTO a table with Computed and Default values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a `TableA` with several columns in it, one of which is a `Computed` value, and another is a `DateTime` with a default value of `GETDATE()`.

Then I have another table, `TableA_Staging`, which I want to use as a raw dumping table for bulk inserts.  This table looks a lot like `TableA` with a few expected differences, one of which being it doesn't have the `Computed` or the `DateTime` column in it.

Once I've done a bulk insert into `TableA_Staging`, I now need to move data from `TableA_Staging` to `TableA`. I'm running into a snag with those two columns. Let's assume  `TableA` looks like this:

```
TableA
-----------
TableAId (INT non-unique, non-auto-incrementing PK)
Column1 (String PK)
Column2
ColumnComputed
ColumnDateTime
```

And...

```
TableA_Staging
-----------
TableAID (this value populated in C# code)
Column1 
Column2
```

Now, I'm trying to do this:

```
INSERT INTO TableA
SELECT TableAID, Column1, Column2 FROM TableA_Staging WHERE TableAID > X
```

But I get this error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I assume it's complaining because I am not providing anything for `ColumnComputed` or `ColumnDateTime`? But if so, I didn't think I would need to provide values for them, as one is computed, and the other has a default value.

Comment: What do you expect?  `TableA` has 5 columns and `TableA_Staging` has 3 columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always include the columns in your insert statement that you are inserting from your select, otherwise you always have to provide the same number of columns in your insert as your select.

Also if your TableID is autoincrement/identity you do not need to include that.

```
INSERT INTO TableA (TableBID, Column1, Column2)
SELECT TableAID, Column1, Column2 
FROM TableA_Staging WHERE TableAID > X
```

Comment: ah, right! That worked :) I will mark as answer when it lets me (in 12 minutes)